# Why process of evaluation don't stop

Tags: tensorflow2.x

`model.evaluate(..., verbose=1)` display line that I can't understand, please can any one explain to me what this mean
`278452/Unknown - 36360s 13ms/step -loss:0.783  - accuracy:0.708`
those numbers increment and the process don't stop. 
It can be because I don't use callbacks ?

Answer (score 1):

This Line show complete detail about each epochs :

1. time of execution for epoch=36360
2. rate at which image is process=13ms/step
3. On average loss on each step/Image from its true prediction=0.783
4. accuracy just correct predict/total/observation=0.708

No callback Just provide efficient path to increase accuracy
Your model showing execution time is to high about 36360 for each epoch

One thing I notice "Unknown" which is unusual generally that seems to me incorrect  here mention thing are (total image process/Total no of Images)

In my case

Epoch 1/20

187/187 [==============================] - 34s 181ms/step - loss: 1.6447 - accuracy: 0.6380